# Additional information: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp

При создании Поста возникает ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сама реализация поста

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddNewPost()
    {
        List<int> numlist = new List<int>();
        int num = 0;
        var posts = _blogRepository.GetPosts();
        if (posts.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (var post in posts)
            {
                var postid = post.Id;
                Int32.TryParse(postid, out num);
                numlist.Add(num);
            }
            numlist.Sort();
            num = numlist.Last();
            num++;
        }
        else
        {
            num = 1;
        }
        var newid = num.ToString();
        PostViewModel model = new PostViewModel();
        model.ID = newid;
        return View(model);
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult AddNewPost(PostViewModel model)
    {
        var post = new Post
        {
            Id = model.ID,
            Body = model.Body,
            Meta = model.Meta,
            PostedOn = DateTime.Now,
            Published = true,
            ShortDescription = model.ShortDescription,
            Title = model.Title,
            UrlSeo = model.UrlSeo
        };
        _blogRepository.AddNewPost(post);
        return RedirectToAction("EditPost", "Blog", new { slug = model.UrlSeo });
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Не нашлось объекта, удовлетворяющего условию в `Where`. Проверяйте результат `FirstOrDefault` на `null`.

```
var found = _context.Posts.Where(...).FirstOrDefault();
return (found == null)? null : found.Id;
```

*Update*

Еще раз - объект `Post` не найден. `GetPostIdBySlug` вернул `null` в качестве `postid`.  По этому  `postid` никакой `Post` не нашелся. Переменная `post` - `null`.

Comment: Я уже делал писал вот так    return _context.Posts.Where(x => x.UrlSeo == slug).FirstOrDefault()?.Id; Ничего не вышло( Появилась другая ошибка

Comment: @KhmulkoPavel И что, компилировалось?

Comment: Cделал как вы сказали и теперь новая ошибка. скинул сверху скрин

Comment: Нууу и как пофиксить?

Comment: @KhmulkoPavel Откуда я знаю, как "пофиксить"? Это же Ваша программа. Во вью проверяйте `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ID)`, и выводите сообщение, что соответствующий пост не найден.

Comment: @KhmulkoPavel А в `CreatePostViewModel` заверните код, обращающийся к свойствам поста, в проверку `if (post != null) { ... }`.

Comment: ничего не ясно!

Comment: Странно, а мне все ясно :).

Comment: т.е так сразу и не скажешь в чем проблема?

Comment: @KhmulkoPavel Я уже сказал Вам в чем проблема: на найден `Post`. Почему это произошло, знаете только Вы.